# In Magento, on submitting the registation form; throws a new Exception()

Tags: email, magento

I am creating a custom Registration form. On submitting the form it has to generate a mail but now it is throwing a new Exception(); error. Guide me on how to solve this problem

my code

```
<?php

class Huntgather_Registration_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT  = 'contacts/huntgather_registration/recipient_email';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER     = 'contacts/huntgather_registration/sender_email_identity';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE   = 'contacts/huntgather_registration/email_template';
    const XML_PATH_ENABLED          = 'contacts/huntgather_registration/enabled';

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();

        if( !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED) ) {
            $this->norouteAction();
        }
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('registrationForm')
            ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['product-name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['serial-number']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['date']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['address']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is($post['data-privacy'], 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('huntgather_registration')->__('Your registration has been processed. Thank you for registering your product'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('huntgather_registration')->__('We were unable to process your registration. Please make sure you have entered all required data in the form below'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
}
```

Form submit getting error

(We were unable to process your registration. Please make sure you have entered all required data in the form below)

Comment: Post complete error message

Comment: @DushyantJoshi: After submitting the form this is the error i am getting "(We were unable to process your registration. Please make sure you have entered all required data in the form below)".

Comment: The error says it all. You are not filling the required data. ANd one more thing. Why are you throwing an exception if the form failed to validate. Instead use some more useful error messages

Comment: @DushyantJoshi: I filled up all the required fields,but still throwing the same error. if i remove the mail functionality code its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got an exception while sending email. You should replace

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('huntgather_registration')->__('We were unable to process your registration. Please make sure you have entered all required data in the form below'));
```

With

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
```

to get problem exactly.